# не срабатывает grep

Tags: grep, bash

ввожу dhclient -v eth0 | greb 192
dhclient получает адрес 192.168.0.1/32 
я хочу узнать какой именно он получит ип.

Есть еще кучу других вариантов, но меня заинтересовал вопрос почему grep не сработал?

Comment: может потому что он grep, а не greb ? С другой стороны, может dhclient выводи не в стандартный поток, а в поток для вывода ошибок?

Comment: я опечатался

Comment: почему не просто

    dhclient -v eth0 | grep 192

?

Comment: Так я так и делаю!!! Но вываливается весь мусор...

Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.2.4-P2 Gentoo-r1
Copyright 2004-2012 Internet Systems Consortium.
All rights reserved.
For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/

Corrupt lease file - possible data loss!
Listening on LPF/eth0/90:2b:34:15:45:17
Sending on   LPF/eth0/90:2b:34:15:45:17
Sending on   Socket/fallback
DHCPREQUEST on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67
DHCPACK from 192.168.0.1
bound to 192.168.0.103 -- renewal in 814 seconds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dhclient -v eth0 2>&1 | grep 192

Comment: А почему именно так?
как это работает?

Comment: @zinteco: про разницу между stdout и stderr знаете? Если нет, почитайте [википедию](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8).